# GOOGLE SHEETS: Help needed to sum a range of cells across rows, where the range is controlled by a variable

Tags: google-sheets, select, sum, range, row

I need to sum a range of cells across rows, but I need to be able to specify the amount with a variable.

For example.
If i write 5 in cell B1, I want to sum range A1:A5.
If i write 10 in cell B1, I want to sum range A1:A10.
If i write 20 in cell B1, I want to sum range A1:A20.

And so on.

Does anyone know a formula for this?

Kind regards.

I tried writing( in cell B1) =SUM(A1:A(1+B1)). This didn't work at all, instead a =NAME? appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `INDIRECT` to set a range by joining text, like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&B1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula will also work:

`=SUM(BYROW(SEQUENCE(B1),LAMBDA(ROW,INDEX(A1:A,ROW))))`

`SEQUENCE()` return an array of rows count up from 1 by default.

`BYROW()` can use an array as row reference and apply a `LAMBDA()` function to each row.

`INDEX()` return the `CELL` the matches a given `INDEX` of `ROW` and `COL`.

`SUM` sum up every value of a range (array).

Answer (score 0):

also possibility:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A; B1))
```

or:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:INDEX(A:A; B1))
```